# document on change function to run when a class "moves"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple script below where my buttons add a class to a single div element. I want to write a function that prints `hi` to the console whenever myClass moves, anyone have any tips?

```js
 changeCurrent = function(id) {
    $("div").removeClass("myClass")
    $("#" + id + "").addClass("myClass");
  }

// I want to print hello every time we click a button 
// by detecting whenever the "current" class moves
$('document').on('change', '.section', function() {
  console.log("hello")
})
```

```css
.myClass {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onClick="changeCurrent('hi')">Hi</button>
<button onClick="changeCurrent('hello')">Hello</button>
<button onClick="changeCurrent('howdy')">Howdy</button>

<div class="section myClass" id="hi">Hi</div>
<div class="section" id="hello">Hello</div>
<div class="section" id="howdy">Howdy</div>
```

Comment: The `change` event is only triggered when the user changes an input element, not when a class changes.

Comment: Thanks, do you have any idea on how I should approach this instead?